# Filter out null values from a Seq[JsValue]

Tags: scala

I have a Seq defined like:

```
val s: Seq[JsValue] = Seq(JsString("Plain Donut"), JsString("Strawberry Donut"), JsString("Glazed Donut") , JsString("") , JsString("") , JsString("Asds") , JsString("") , JsString(null))
```

I want to create another sequence without those empty values or remove the empty values from the existing sequence.

I'm trying something like:

```
s.filterNot(_ == JsString(""))
```

This works fine. I'm able to remove the empty values. But when it comes to removing the null value like:

```
s.filterNot(_ == JsString(null))
```

or:

```
s.filterNot(_ == null)
```

That way does not work. The null value still comes out when I try to `println(s)`.

Comment: That should work and do exactly what you want

Comment: What does "does not work properly" mean ? What is your output ? Your command should work (I prefer using `_.isEmpty` though, this is not important)

Comment: And similarly if I give `(_ == null)` should also work for null values too?

Comment: @BlueSheepToken I get the entire sequence without anything being filtered out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try:

```
s.filterNot(jsonValue => jsonValue == JsString("") || jsonValue == JsNull)
```

Since there is a separate JsNull class for null values.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
val r = s.filterNot(List(JsString(""), null, JsString(null)).contains)
```

where `println(r)` outputs

```
List("Plain Donut", "Strawberry Donut", "Glazed Donut", "Asds")
```

Comment: I tested this with `play-json`, and it works - what library do you use?

Comment: `"com.typesafe.play" %% "play" % "2.7.3"`

Answer (score 1):

That is because the `s` is immutable and the result will not be stored in `s` variable in your case.
Store the result in some other variable and log that variable.

```
import play.api.libs.json.{JsString, JsValue}
val s: Seq[JsValue] = Seq(JsString("Plain Donut"), JsString("Strawberry Donut"), JsString("Glazed Donut") , JsString("") , JsString("") ,JsString("Asds") , JsString("") , JsString(null))
print(s.filterNot(v => (v == JsString(null) || v == null || v == JsString(""))))
```

Check this https://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections_1.html

Comment: I'm trying to print, and not store. Still, This didn't work. I also tried `null` , `""`,  `JsString(null)` and `JsString("null")`

Comment: You are trying to print `s` but `s` will always have all the values. You will have to store the filtered value in something and then print it.

Comment: I was trying to print `s.filterNot()`

Comment: Well i tried the above and it worked with import play.api.libs.json.{JsString, JsValue}